# How to create push notification when the RSS feed gets updated in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, rss

I need to display a push notification on new updates in the xml feed.
Had gone through  http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services  and tried that sample code successfully.
But  what should I need to  do ,to create push notification while new entries come in RSS feed?

Comment: Did you, by any chance, published an application with that kind of feature? Because I have never been able to find an application that push notifications upon new RSS entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a push notification provider server that sends the actual remote push notification as well.

I suggest you have a look at this link

http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/